# reading and importing data from external wikis

Tags: import, mediawiki, article

I need to write a Mediawiki extension that it can read other wikis articles (by user selection) and user can select some articles and then import them to the user's Mediawiki. 
How should i write it?

Comment: If you think "the other way round" https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Push might be what you need it pushes from one wiki to another instead of importing